# Добавление метки "pocketsphinx"

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, создание-метки

Прошу добавить метку **pocketsphinx** для пакета Pocketsphinx (Python)

Comment: Дайте ссылку хотя бы на 1 на вопрос, к которому ее стоит добавить

Comment: Готово. Добавил к вопросу https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/944659/pocketsphinx-не-видит-слово-в-словаре